# Custom Activity Not moving to the next step on the Interaction

Tags: journeybuilder

I have created a custom activity and it is doing what it should. However, once the execution is completed, it is not moving to the next activity on the journey. Just wondering if anyone has experienced the same? Any direction on how to solve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Nic, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and when I removed the outArgument from the config.json the subscribers started moving through the journey.  In my case the activity was endlessly waiting for a response that never came.